# Can I get a typed value from HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

The further I get into this the hairier it becomes (except for hair on my head, not much of it left there now).

What I am trying to do is to create a generic container for case classes and have the ability to retrieve its fields in typed fashion, e.g. var x: Int = m('age)

Here is a small setup:

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist._
import ops.record.{Keys, Values}

case class Bar(name: String, age: Int)

class Morphic[H <: HList](h: H) {
  def apply[S <: Symbol, K <: HList, V <: HList](s: S)(implicit
                                                       keys: Keys.Aux[H, K],
                                                       values: Values.Aux[H, V],
                                                       ktl: ToList[K, Any],
                                                       vtl: ToList[V, Any]) = {
    import shapeless.record._
    (h.keys.toList zip h.values.toList).toMap.getOrElse(s, None) // <-- is there a way to achive this without going through Map
  }

  def apply(n: Nat)(implicit at: At[H, n.N]): at.Out = h(at)
}

object Morphic {
  def apply[A, H <: HList](p: A)(implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, H]) = {
    new Morphic(gen.to(p))
  }
}

object testApp extends App {

  var f = Bar("John", 25)
  var m1 = Morphic(f)
  val ageByName = m1('age)
  println(s"ageByName(value=${ageByName}, type=${ageByName.getClass})")
  val ageByPos = m1(1)
  println(s"ageByName(value=${ageByPos}, type=${ageByPos.getClass})")

  //val ageByName1: Int = m1('age) // <-- compile time error, Any does not match Int
  //val ageByPos1: Int = m1(1)  // <-- compile time error, at.Out does not match Int

  // As I want to do this without using asInstanceOf(Int)
  // val isAdult: Boolean = ageByName > 22
}
```

Just getting values works but they are not typed at compile time

I have two problems here I am trying to solve:

1. Can I get `val ageByName1: Int = m1('age)` to work?
2. What's an easier way to retrieve the value form HList given the symbol (and hopefully so that I can assign it to var with specified type)

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using lenses? If so, look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039655/shapeless-generic-lens-parameterized-by-case-class-or-field

Comment: Looks promising, i'll give it a try once I figure out sbt dependencies for Scala 2.12